# Disable a parameter input at selection screen

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

I have screen filter at selection screen like this

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK a WITH FRAME.
PARAMETERS s_werks like resb-werks DEFAULT 'X' .

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_aufnr FOR in_param-aufnr,
                s_matnr FOR in_param-matnr,
                s_bldat FOR in_param-bldat.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK a.
```

and I want to disable just `s_werks` parameter but `SELECT-OPTIONS`.

I want to disable it because it'll be exact value which is filled from table depends on the `sy-uname` :)

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `OUTPUT` selection screen event for this.
Add the following code:

```
AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-name = 'S_WERKS'.
      screen-input = 0.
      MODIFY SCREEN.
    ENDIF.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Changing the `input` value to `0` for this screen element will disable input and makes the input field appear as grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

You may define the parameter non-vivible with `no-display`.

```
parameters:
  s_visib like resb-werks default 'X',
  s_werks like resb-werks default 'X' no-display.
```

René's solution is usefull, when you want to define the visibility dynamic.